# .click() doesn't work with (document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

My `jQuery('a[data-filter=".hottop"]').click();` doesn't work together with my document.ready function. The click works fine when fired from console, and document.ready fires everything else just fine. It just doesn't trigger the click.

Can someone figure out why?

[Live Page](http://indeklimadanmark.dk/vidensbank/). Site isn't public yet, so please identify with stackof//123O

Comment: If no event handler is bounded with element use `jQuery('a[data-filter=".hottop"]')[0].click();`

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. This makes it more easy to answer the question.

Comment: @Satpal -> Unfortunately, that doesnt make any difference.
I'm not sure how to make the example better. If I reproduce on jsfiddle everything works fine, so the problem must lie in the page somewhere..

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I can't explain why it is happening, I used to experience the same thing and I'm creating DOM elements dynamically. Could you try this

```
            $("body").on('click', 'yourClass/ID-Element', function () {
       //your codes
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Using the following function made everything work:

```
$(window).load(function()
```

Thanks!